# Why does my webpage not work with <!DOCTYPE html....> but it works with <!DOCTYPE xhtml>?

Tags: html, css

I am making a web page and I am nearing completion, so I decided to put it through an html validator, and I had a bunch of errors with my page. My page works currently with `<!DOCTYPE xhtml><html>...` but when I type `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">` my page's spacing breaks.

Examples: Picture of when it works[image: What it is supposed to look like]

Code: `<!DOCTYPE xhtml>
       <html ng-app="ticTacToe" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999.xhtml">`

What happens when I add the proper code:[image]

Code:`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0   Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
      <html ng-app="ticTacToe" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999.xhtml">`

So my question is, how can I make the spacing work, with the more valid code? It looks like the CSS selector "top: " that I am using is not working. Any feedback will be greatly appreciated. Let me know if you need more info, thanks in advance!

UPDATE: Direct CSS that is responsible for that part

```
#bodyArea
{
    width: 425px;
    position: relative;
    top: 30%;
    left: 40%;
}
```

Comment: You'll have to provide at least some code from your website. Try using only `<!doctype html>` and let us know what happens.

Comment: Probably best stick to <!doctype html> (it's 2015)

Comment: @AmarSyla i changed it to '<!doctype html>' and nothing changed and I have a lot of code for it so far, but I will update my post with a snippet of the direct css that positions it

Comment: @DanWhite I thought xhtml was more modern? haha My school taught me to do it the <!doctype xhtml> way

Comment: @Austin Basically, both `<!doctype html>` and `<!doctype html>` are the same modernity level. They are just two different things. You use `html` when you're simply coding HTML, or `xhtml` when you're specifically coding XHTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is **validation**.

Run your page through the validator at http://validator.w3.org/ with both tags and note the differences.

XHTML and HTML5 are different, so if the page is coded the same way, it is possible it will not render properly when you use an XHTML doctype.

The doctype tells the browser how to interpret the code for the page.  The HTML (or XHTML) should **always** validate to ensure your page displays properly over the greatest number of browsers.

Reference for the differences: http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/differences-html-xhtml/